# Book on Meinong's theory of objects

Tags: metaphysics, reference-request, ontology, being

Could anyone please recommend a book to begin to learn about Meinong's theory of objects and "Meinong's Jungle". I thought a good one might be "Meinong's Theory of Objects and Values" by Findlay (1963), but I can't find even a used copy anywhere that isn't prohibitively expensive.

Comment: Starter Kit: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/meinong/ (haven't read it yet)

Comment: A good modern exposition of Meinongianism, with motivation, history and relation to modern debates is [Berto's Existence as a Real Property: The Ontology of Meinongianism](https://books.google.com/books/about/Existence_as_a_Real_Property.html?id=UobUqRMyUawC), and it is freely available on [PhilArchive](https://philarchive.org/archive/BEREAA-2v2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have Findlay's book but do not recommend it. It is an early work, not one of mature exposition, and hardly luminous in its clarity. Its scholarship is also now unavoidably dated.

Try :

Grossmann, Reinhardt : Meinong (Arguments of the Philosophers). ISBN 10: 0710078315 / ISBN 13: 9780710078315
Published by Routledge Kegan & Paul, 1974.

Also of use :

Swanson, Carolyn : Reburial of Nonexistents: Reconsidering the Meinong-Russell Debate (Value Inquiry Book) (Central European Value Studies). ISBN 10: 9042033649 / ISBN 13: 9789042033641
Published by Rodopi, 2011.

More venturesome :

Lambert, Karel: Meinong and the Principle of Independence: Its Place in Meinong's Theory of Objects and its Significance in Contemporary Philosophical Logic (Modern European Philosophy). ISBN 10: 0521271991 / ISBN 13: 9780521271998
Published by Cambridge University Press, 1983.

All of these are easily available at non-outrageous prices.

Answer (score 4):

Some references :

- Dale Jacquette, [Alexius Meinong : The Shepherd of Non-Being](https://books.google.it/books?id=7jswCgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Springer (2015)
- Francesco Berto, [Existence as a Real Property : The Ontology of Meinongianism](https://books.google.it/books?id=UobUqRMyUawC&pg=PA1), Springer (2013)
- Kenneth Perszyk, [Nonexistent Objects : Meinong and Contemporary Philosophy](https://books.google.it/books?id=zSbgCRqbiyQC&printsec=frontcover), Springer (1993)
- Jacek Paśniczek, [The Logic of Intentional Objects : A Meinongian Version of Classical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=8zL0CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA1), Springer  (1998).

To be published :

- [Exploring Meinong’s Jungle and Beyond (Springer 2018)](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9783319787916)

Comment: I was going to post about the Routley book, but I see it's mentioned here. It would be nice to include the release date in this answer, and some information about why that book might be helpful (I'm hopeful about Hyde's article).